# NSMutableArray debug

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, nsmutablearray

I read now Apple's guide about collections, and try to see their code. When I watched code step by step I saw something strange for me

[image]

Why in right colomn strings not under its indexes? And why string `@"222"` shown like `nil`?

Comment: that's a known error of Xcode, as you can see in the NSLog output your array is working as expected

Comment: yeah, I try it after found this bug. Early I didn't bring attention to it. It is bug of Xcode with only arrays?

Comment: you should look into using LLDB. All those NSLog statements are not necessary if you don't want. You can run commands in the output. Just type 'po array' to get the value in the array where your breakpoint is.